# Java collisions not working

Tags: java, collision

I have made a few threads asking for help with collisions in the past and have made some progress, I am making a 2D Java game where the player on the screen moves with the keyboard input, the problem is, on my background (the map) there are many obstacles and at the moment my player just walks straight through them, so far with the help of users from this forum I have got this code in my code to detect the collisions:

```
 public void changeBuckyPos(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
  float newX = buckyPositionX + deltaX;
  float newY = buckyPositionY + deltaY;

  // check for collisions
  Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle((int)newX, (int)newY, 40, 40);
  Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(-100, -143, 70,70);

  if (!rectOne.intersects(rectTwo)) {
    buckyPositionX = newX;        
    buckyPositionY = newY;        
  }
}
```

There are now no errors with this code when I put it into my game, but a bigger problem has occurred, although this code comes up with no errors, it just does nothing, I mean when I go onto the game there is no collision, nothing is happening when the two rectangles intersect, could anyone please help me with this, I have been stuck with it for a very long time.

Thank you.

Comment: Well... what *should* happen when two rectangles meet? The code your provide just only makes that, if the new position intersect, then the position is not updated.

Comment: How do you use this function?

Comment: Debug the method, try adding some thorough logging and explore the results. Is it being called? Is it being called with the right arguments? Is the output of it used at all? So many questions...

Comment: You say, you got many obstacles, but your function just checks intersection with one single rectangle, and that with negative coordinates. For a start, I'd say, you must check against all obstacle's boundaries.

Comment: If you draw the rectangle(s), do they appear where you expect them to? (asking since rectTwo will appear outside your window unless you transform the coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

- It's better to maintain a unique datatype for your game entities
- Update [of class game] should be called periodically in a separate thread
- Draw in another thread also  periodically

Your game logic should be something like (Almost full Java Psydocode):

```
public class Block{
    int speedX;
    int speedY;
    Rectangle rect;
    public void update(){
         rect.x+=speedX;
         rect.y+=speedY; 
    }
    public void draw(/*Graphics g..or somthing*/){
         //draw this single object
    }
    ..getters and setters..
}

public class Game{
    List<Block> obstacles; 
    Block myBlock();   
    ......
    void update(){
        ...
       myBlock.update();
       for(Block ob: obstacles){               
           if(myBlock.getRect().intersects(ob.getRect())){
                  processCollision(ob);
           }
           ob.update();
       }
       ...
    }
    public void draw(/*Graphics g..or somthing*/){
           //background draw logic
           myBlock.draw(g);
           for(Block ob: obstacles)
               ob.draw(g);
    }
    void processCollision(Rect ob){
          ..
          do whatever you want with ob
          ..
    }
}
```